# Display validation messages when a button is clicked

Tags: angularjs, forms, angular-material, ng-messages

I think what I want to achieve is quite simple. Let's have a form with a required field, a select for instance (I've also tried it with an input and it's exactly the same situation anyway).

I want to display the `ng-messages` only when a button is clicked. If the form field was touched before clicking the button, it works fine. But I cannot do it if the form field is `$untouched`.

I've solved it setting programatically `$touched` to the form field, but I'm wondering if there is any way to solve it without this uggly 'hack'.

```
// Any way to avoid this line??
$scope.myForm.favoriteColor.$setTouched();
//
```

Code for reference:

HTML:

```
<md-input-container>
    <label>Favorite Color</label>
    <md-select name="favoriteColor" ng-model="favoriteColor" required>
      <md-option value="red">Red</md-option>
      <md-option value="blue">Blue</md-option>
    </md-select>
    <div class="errors" ng-messages="myForm.favoriteColor.$error" ng-show="validateWithHack">
      <div ng-message="required">Required</div>
    </div>
</md-input-container>
```

JS:

```
$scope.validateWithHack = function() {
  if ($scope.myForm.$valid) {
    alert('Form is valid.');
  } else {
    // Any way to avoid this line??
    $scope.myForm.favoriteColor.$setTouched();
    //
    $scope.validateWithHack = true;
  }
};
```

I'm pretty sure that this was working with previous versions of angular-material. Now I'm using the latest 1.1.1.

> Here is a [plunker](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LRxdbQ) where the
>   problem can be easily reproduced.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the  [CodePen](http://codepen.io/joyblanks/pen/VKPBmd)

I have added `novalidate` to your form and added `type="submit"` to your `md-button`

**Edit 2:** 
The `type="submit"` button actually triggers a form submit and so the angular form validates itself first, What we need to do is to prevent the submit and just do the validation.

`novalidate`(Just to supress the HTML5 validation) to your form and added `type="submit"` to your `md-button` : This Will Validate the form and submit the form, To validate and prevent form submit add `ng-click="submitMethod(<yourForm>, $event)"` to the `<md-button>` and define method as

```
$scope.submitMethod(form,ev){
  ev.preventDefault();
  //rest of your form work say if you want to do ajax or anything you like
  //check if form valid using form.$invalid
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @joyBlanks!, but I'm afraid I cannot set type submit for my use case. I've also tried just setting novalidate, but neither works. Any idea? The ideal solution would be showing the message programatically from the controller...BTW, in your plunker the button type is file, not submit.

Comment: is it because the form submits you cant use type=submit, I would say if you want to override the submit form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()" no?

Comment: Thanks again :) Not sure if I've understood you correctly. Is  [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RGkwGp) what you mean? It seems to be working althought I don't understand why my original code was working in previous versions of angular-material....Please, edit your answer with the suggestions of your comments and I'll accept it. Thanks