# AngularJS material turns required fields to red only after user clicks a field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I have this markup:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm ng-show="$ctrl.isAddMode">
    <label>ID</label>
    <input name="id" ng-model="$ctrl.voice.id"
           ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }"
           ng-change="$ctrl.verifyUniqueId()" required>
    <div class='error' ng-show='$ctrl.idError'>
        {{$ctrl.idError}}
    </div>
</md-input-container>
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input ng-model="$ctrl.voice.name" required>
</md-input-container>
```

and

```
<md-button ng-disabled="!$ctrl.isReadyForSubmit()"
           class="md-raised md-primary"
           ng-click="$ctrl.submit()">
    {{$ctrl.voice.isTest ? "Start Test" : "Publish"}}
</md-button>
```

with:

```
self.isReadyForSubmit = function () {
    return $scope.voiceForm.$valid && !uploadService.getClientErrorMsgOfUploadedFiles();
}
```

I txt turns red if the user clicks on the field, goes out and doesn't fill it.

[image]

However fields that are not clicked by the user don't turn their txt to red.

how can i make them red if the user clicks on the "submit" disabled button?

Comment: I had the same problem and I ended up using an ugly workaround: programatically marking all form fields as $touched before doing the validation. Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645748/angular-material-form-display-validation-messages-when-a-button-is-clicked) could help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the world of angular materials limitations. Take a look at this [code pen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OpdxKJ?editors=1010) I've created. You need to set the css class `md-input-invalid` manually, on `md-input-container` element, if the field is not valide + submit was pressed.

```
<form name="projectForm">
    <md-input-container class="md-block" ng-class="{ 'md-input-invalid': projectForm.description.$invalid  && wasSend }">
        <label>Description</label>
        <input md-maxlength="30" required md-no-asterisk="" name="description" ng-model="project.description">
        <div ng-messages="projectForm.description.$error">
            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
            <div ng-message="md-maxlength">The description must be less than 30 characters long.</div>
        </div>
    </md-input-container>

    <div layout="row">
        <md-input-container flex="50" ng-class="{ 'md-input-invalid': projectForm.clientName.$invalid && wasSend }">
            <label>Client Name*</label>
            <input name="clientName" required ng-model="project.clientName">
            <div ng-messages="projectForm.clientName.$error">
                <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
    <div>
        <md-button type="submit" ng-click="wasSend = true">Submit</md-button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: how would you check for every field `if the field is not valide` ?

Comment: @EladBenda I dont understand your question. Doesn't it work for you?